# sap.ui.common.layout.MatrixLayout Deprecated

Tags: grid, sapui5

I have this code using `sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout`, right now `sap.ui.commons` is deprecated, documentation only said that I have to use `sap.ui.layout.Grid`. But I don´t now how to add rows, cells, add content and créate Separations. I hope you can help me

Using [1.42.6](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.42.6/resources/sap-ui-core.js) UI5 version

```
var oMatrix = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({id:"m1"});
oMatrix.setLayoutFixed(false);

var oMLR = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutRow("m1_1");
oMatrix.addRow(oMLR);   

var oMLC = new sap.ui.layout.GridCell("m1_1_1"); 

var oLabel2 = new sap.m.Label({
    text: 'VIN : '
});
oMLC.setSeparation(sap.ui.commons.layout.Separation.Medium);
oMLC.addContent(oLabel2);
oMLR.addCell(oMLC);
```

Comment: Did you try to look for some tutorials? When looking for sap.ui.layout.grid, I find plenty of them. However, I can't judge on their quality as I have no clue about SAP stuff. Also, please have a look at what makes a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Kindly share the screenshots for better understanding the layout